# Javascript variable getting unset instantly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think the pictures are relatively self explanatory (code matched with console output)

Variable appears to be set to a value, except immediate `console.log` afterwards outputs something different.

**Code:**

[image]

**Console Output**
[image]

**Extended console output (as requested in comments) (extra console.log before and after)**
[image]

Comment: Could you try printing `res.data.fields[i]` twice ?

Comment: well did you check if `$rootScope.user.firstName` is not empty?

Comment: What happens if you put the console log in a `$scope.watch`?

Comment: @mohamedrias I've updated my answer with your request

Comment: @RononDex I know it's not empty because the first console.log of the answer property returns "Kevin" as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not actually a bug.

When you print a primitive, you'll see the state of it when you printed it.

When you work with objects, if you `console.log` them, it only shows the reference. When you click on them, it will show you their current state. So what happened in your case is that the `answer` probably got changed in a later code.

Comment: OP is setting a property in `object` and so it's by reference.

Comment: @mohamedrias That's not true, the 2nd `console.log` is for an object.

Comment: @OmriAharon Turns out you were right! Found an old snippet of code in a completely separate file that was changing it after the fact.

Comment: I just ran `(function() {var a = {}; a.name ="Rias"; console.log(a.name); console.log(a);})()` and it prints as expected

Comment: @mohamedrias Yes, but you haven't changed it. Add a `a.name = "test"` afterwards and see.